# Android build app success but running the app fails

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app, the app ave no compilation errors, but when I try to run the app it gives the following error

```
C:\Users\aomari\Documents\AndroidProjects\tcee\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_split_apk_resources\developmentDebug\instantRunSplitApkResourcesDevelopmentDebug\out\slice_2\resources_ap
```

I have tried to do the following :

1. Restart Android studio.
2. File -> invalidate case / restart
3. Clean the project and rebuild the app.
4. Uninstall the app from the testing device

But unfortunately, all these did not solve the issue.

[image]

Anyone can help me what is this issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Go to folder app-->build--> Delete all folder and run app.

Comment: In the toolstrip on the left of your screenshot, the second button down will toggle you from this tree representation to a classic Gradle console output. Click that button and see if the full console output gives you any clues.

Comment: Please run it on the command line and paste output here.

```gradlew.bat clean assembleDebug```

Comment: Disable Instant Run !

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the following line from the manifest file

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

and added the following line to the manifest application

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

and created the following file at XML folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and this is fixed the issue.
This was strange and I still do not know why that happened and why this fixed the issue.